# Angular 4: Where should third party plugins be declared CoreModule or AppModule?

Tags: angular, angular5

My Angular4 project uses multiple third party packages and many of these are used in different Core Module, Lazy loaded features. Is it a good practice to declare the third party packages in Core Module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare third party modules in App module or core modules.

If you declare in App Module, the import code will be long. To avoid that we introduced core module to import necessary modules, services. In my project, we have included ionic-native services, app singleton services in core module.

Finally core modules will be imported to app modules